# Running spring boot from console doesn't include swagger

Tags: java, maven, jar, swagger, executable-jar

I have a problem with spring boot application with swagger.
My application.properties includes a line `springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger` and when I run through Intellij or mvn spring-boot:run then all is fine and I can access swagger at `localhost:8080/swagger`

However after I build jar file and I run it with `java -jar target/testproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` there is an error when I try to access swagger. My resource endpoints are accessible.

This is my pom file:

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
        <spring.version>3.0.0</spring.version>
        <springdoc.openapi.version>2.0.2</springdoc.openapi.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.openapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.rad.TestProjectApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Do you know how to build a jar file or launch it properly so that swagger is accessible?

Ideally I want to run it in docker container so I have an instruction: `CMD ["java", "-jar", "/testrepository/app.jar"]` in my Dockerfile

Comment: Try use Spring Boot version 2.7.9 not 3.0.

Comment: I suspect that application.properties not being on the classpath, tether than swagger is the issue